# IIS7 returning 500 for status code 401 when asp.net mvc app writes it to the response

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis-7

Our mvc application sets the response status code to 401 and sets TrySkipIisCustomErrors to true under some circumstances.

I can see from the IIS log that it is getting this status code:

```
2012-05-04 01:32:42 10.212.98.183 POST /v1.07/session - 80 - 10.24.22.26 curl/7.20.1+(i686-pc-cygwin)+libcurl/7.20.1+OpenSSL/0.9.8r+zlib/1.2.5+libidn/1.18+libssh2/1.2.5 401 0 0 48325
```

However the response I receive in the client is 500:

```
< HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
< Content-Type: text/html
< Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.0
< Date: Fri, 04 May 2012 02:31:18 GMT
< Content-Length: 75
<
* Connection #0 to host webserver left intact
* Closing connection #0
The page cannot be displayed because an internal server error has occurred.
```

I have tried various other settings in the web.config for the mvc application around httpErrors and customErrors, none of which seem to make a difference.

How can I configure IIS to return the actual response and not 500?

Comment: Something more is going on. IIS will return 401 Unauthorized. Create a new Web App and test it.

Comment: Yeah it seems that we have a <system.webServer><httpErrors> section in our web config. As soon as we removed that (or allowed changes to it in applicationHost.config) the correct status code was returned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So after a lot more googling, I changed the applicationHost.config file to allow delegation of httpErrors and now I get the correct response back to the client.

I had to set the following from Deny to Allow:

```
<section name="httpErrors" overrideModeDefault="Allow" />
```

I tried to follow the instructions in the file to use a `<location>` tag:

```
<location path="" overrideMode="Allow">
  <system.webServer>
    <httpErrors />
  </system.webServer>
</location>
```

but this did not work. It would work if I specified the web site in the path, rather than all sites though, however, I want to allow it for all the sites on the web server.

Comment: Note: By default, most IIS 7.0 sections in applicationHost.config are locked down, and none of the .NET framework are locked (including the ASP.NET sections in the <system.web> section group in machine.config and root web.config).